# Promise to select from dropdown in typescript

Tags: angularjs, selenium, typescript, promise, protractor

I am new to typescript and I wanted to write a promise to select options based on text from drop down.
This is what I am doing but it's failing -

```
case 'SelectFromList':
     return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
         this.retrieveElement(driverscr.getPageElementFromJson(screenName, fieldName)) // retrieveElement gets the page element.
             .click()
             .then(() => {
                 resolve();
             })
             .thenCatch( () => {
                 reject();
             });
       });
```

Comment: @TehBeardedOne Any clue on this one ?

Comment: I've never tried to select a dropdown option the way you are doing it here. I've had success other ways but I'm not sure about how to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment above I've never tried to select an item from a dropdown the way you are doing it. Here is an example that has worked for me in the past. In my example I have a dropdown menu that has a list of domains I want to add a user to. I find the option that matches the domain I am looking for and click it. Hope this helps you find a solution.

```
public static domainSelectorList = element.all(by.repeater("d in vm.customer.domains")

public static addUserToDomain(domain: string): Promise<void> {
    return this.domainSelectorList.filter((elem: ElementFinder) =>
        elem.getWebElement()
            .getInnerHtml()
            .then((innerHtml: string) =>
                innerHtml.indexOf(`@${domain}`) > -1)).first().click();
}
```